# Data from Json query not getting populated in Android Text View

Tags: android, jsoup

I used Json 1.9.2 library in Android to parse data from a website and then set the resulting data to a TextView in Android. But I am not able to set the fetched data on the TextView.

Sharing the relevant code. I'm using Fragments.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    tv1 = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.trending_textView);

    new Title().execute();


}

private class Title extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String title;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Fetching the latest trends");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("#Trends");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

            Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("a");

            for (Element link : links) {
                //String linkHref = link.attr("href");
                linkText = link.text();

                //System.out.println("#"+linkText);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        tv1.setText(linkText.toString());
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does `mProgressDialog.dismiss()` work?

Comment: What does `linkText` print in `doInBackground`?

Comment: Problem got resolved after I removed the loop

Answer (score 0):

you have to post the task result into UI thread by returning the result in doInbackground() method 
and u will receive the result in onPostExecute() as argument , then you populate the views from there since onPostExecute() runs in UI thread 
for more info :-

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    tv1 = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.trending_textView);

    new Title().execute();


}

private class Title extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Elements> {
    String title;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Fetching the latest trends");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("#Trends");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public Elements doInBackground(Void... params) {
       Elements links ; 
        try {

            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

             links = doc.getElementsByTag("a");

            } catch (Exeption e ) {

                return null ;
        }


        return links;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Elements ...links) {

           if(links.get(0) == null) return ;
           for (Element link : links.get(0)) {
            //String linkHref = link.attr("href");
            linkText = link.text();
            // u might add scrolling behavior 
            tv.append(linktext + "\n");
            //System.out.println("#"+linkText);
        }


    }
}
```